# 28x28 Canvas ctx.getImageData() returning big array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

i need help with my code please, im making a IA  handwritting recognition, so first im trying to single pixel draw into a 28x28 canvas, so, when i use ctx.GetImageData().data, i can get an 28x28 array with values from 0 - 255, instead, im getting a 3135 sized array. I dont know if im doing the right thing, here is my code:

```js
// Variables for referencing the canvas and 2dcanvas context
var canvas, ctx;

// Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status
var mouseX, mouseY, mouseDown = 0;

// Draws a dot at a specific position on the supplied canvas name
// Parameters are: A canvas context, the x position, the y position, the size of the dot
function drawDot(ctx, x, y) {
  let pxData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 28, 28);
  pxData.data[0] = 0;
  pxData.data[1] = 0;
  pxData.data[2] = 0;
  pxData.data[3] = 255;
  ctx.putImageData(pxData, x, y);
}

// Clear the canvas context using the canvas width and height
function clearCanvas(canvas, ctx) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location
function sketchpad_mouseDown() {
  mouseDown = 1;
  drawDot(ctx, mouseX, mouseY);
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being released
function sketchpad_mouseUp() {
  mouseDown = 0;
}

// Keep track of the mouse position and draw a dot if mouse button is currently pressed
function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) {
  // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved
  getMousePos(e);

  // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed
  if (mouseDown == 1) {
    drawDot(ctx, mouseX, mouseY);
  }
}

// Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas
function getMousePos(e) {
  if (!e)
    var e = event;

  if (e.offsetX) {
    mouseX = e.offsetX;
    mouseY = e.offsetY;
  } else if (e.layerX) {
    mouseX = e.layerX;
    mouseY = e.layerY;
  }
}

// Set-up the canvas and add our event handlers after the page has loaded
function init() {
  // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
  canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

  // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas
  if (canvas.getContext)
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers
  if (ctx) {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketchpad_mouseUp, false);
  }
}

function exportData() {
  // const normalarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(imgdata);
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,28,28);
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sketchpad</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <style>
        #sketchpad {
            border: 1px solid #888;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<div id="sketchpadapp">
    <canvas id="sketchpad" height="28" width="28" style="display: block"></canvas>
    <button type="button" onclick="exportData()">Get array</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 28*28*4 happens to be 3136

Comment: So im getting a RGBA array list?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) - ImageData.data is a Uint8ClampedArray representing a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255 (inclusive).

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Problem solved.